# Styling table using properties

Tags: html

I'm looking over some (very) old worksheets I did for HTML many moons ago and noticed a question that says to "style" a table using only `table` properties. The simple question is, **how** do I get the table to look like the one below by just using properties? I appreciate this way of doing things is deprecated, but would still very much like to find a solution.

Below is my attempt (with a JSFiddle link, too), and an image oh how it should look at the end of it.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="2" frame="box" cellspacing="2" width="40%">
            <tr><th>Year 2010</th>  <th>Jan-April</th> <th>May-August</th>  <th>September-December </th></tr>
            <tr><td>Sales</td>  <td>200,000</td>    <td>225,000</td> <td>185,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Costs</td>  <td>78,000</td> <td>110,000</td>    <td>125,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Profit</td> <td>122,000</td>    <td>125,000 </td><td>60,000</td></tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

The question from the worksheet states:
**Try to use the table properties so that the table looks like this [image]:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxLrap2/)

[image: table]

Comment: By "properties" do you mean "HTML attributes"? You can't. HTML isn't as powerful at doing presentation as CSS.

Comment: @Quentin style is HTML attribute as well =D

Comment: @Quentin No, I mean the properties available to table (like in my example, <table border="2" property="foo" property="bar" etc). Given that image, there is no way to recreate it using table properties alone, is that what you're saying? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @TEK — Those are HTML attributes.

Comment: You don't need to stick to just `table` attributes, if what you're trying is to have an _old school_ way of doing this. You still can use tags like `<b>`, `<center>`, etc.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/6rxLrap2/5/

Comment: @Quentin Well, the question in the worksheet states "Try to use the table properties so that the table looks like this".

Comment: @MelanciaUK No, because it doesn't match the image posted. :)

Comment: Oh yes. The borders...

Comment: @TEK — "table properties" is not a technical term. It might mean obsolete attributes. It might mean "CSS properties".

Comment: I think it's better now: http://jsfiddle.net/6rxLrap2/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I started web development long after those HTML properties were deprecated, so this is the first time I've actually used them. I have no idea how to create the double border effect, but this is my best attempt:

```html
<table border="3" bgcolor="#000" cellspacing="1"
       cellpadding="6" rules="cols" width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#fff">
      <div><b><i>Year 2010</i></b></div>
      <div><b><i>Sales</i></b></div>
      <div><b><i>Costs</i></b></div>
      <div><b><i>Profits</i></b></div>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#fff">
      <div><b><i>Jan-April</i></b></div>
      <div align="right">200,000</div>
      <div align="right">78,000</div>
      <div align="right">122,000</div>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#fff">
      <div><b><i>May-August</i></b></div>
      <div align="right">225,000</div>
      <div align="right">110,000</div>
      <div align="right">125,000</div>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#fff">
      <div><b><i>September-December</i></b></div>
      <div align="right">185,000</div>
      <div align="right">125,000</div>
      <div align="right">60,000</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Table example]

This obviously ignores the `style` attribute altogether.

I don't know if it counts as cheating to only use 1 row and 4 cells in total - I did this to allow me to kind of generate padding at the sides of each (fake) cell, but not at the top or bottom.

I used `rules="cols"` to allow for a thicker outer border (as I couldn't create the double border effect). Removing this makes the inner border as thick as the outer border.

I guess the double border could be generated by wrapping the `table` element in two `div` elements - the outermost with a `bgcolor` property set to `#000` and the table's parent with a `bgcolor` of `#fff` - I don't know you'd go about creating a 1px gap between each though.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`rules`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.1) attributes:

```
<table frame="box" rules="cols" border="2px" cellspacing="2" width="40%" >
</table>
```

**It's OLD and not acceptable as a good practice nowadays, don't use this in a real environment.** User CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to move backwards, but that's it:

```html
<table border="2" frame="frame" rules="cols" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th><i>Year 2010</i></th>
    <th><i>Jan-April</i></th>
    <th><i>May-August</i></th>
    <th><i>September-December</i></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><i>Sales</i></b></td>
    <td align="right">200,000</td>
    <td align="right">225,000</td>
    <td align="right">185,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><i>Costs</i></b></td>
    <td align="right">78,000</td>
    <td align="right">110,000</td>
    <td align="right">125,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><i>Profit</i></b></td>
    <td align="right">122,000</td>
    <td align="right">125,000</td>
    <td align="right">60,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxLrap2/9/)